# How to use the dotnet/iot Mfrc522 library

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi, iot, mfrc522

I want to read data from a NFC tag with my RC522 connected to a raspberry pi. I like c# programming much more then Python so i decided to use the dotnet/iot library Mfrc522 (https://github.com/dotnet/iot/tree/main/src/devices/Mfrc522).

But with the Mfrc522 Library i do not get any card information.

```
int pinReset = 22;
board = Board.Create();
GpioController gpioController = board.CreateGpioController();

SpiConnectionSettings connection = new(0, 1);
// Here you can use as well MfRc522.MaximumSpiClockFrequency which is 10_000_000
// Anything lower will work as well
connection.ClockFrequency = 5_000_000;
SpiDevice spi = board.CreateSpiDevice(connection);
mfrc522 = new(spi, pinReset, gpioController, false);

bool res;

Console.WriteLine("Start Listening");

Data106kbpsTypeA card;
do
{
    res = mfrc522.ListenToCardIso14443TypeA(out card, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    Thread.Sleep(res ? 0 : 200);
}
while (!res);

Console.WriteLine("CardFound");


Console.WriteLine();
if (UltralightCard.IsUltralightCard(card.Atqa, card.Sak))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ultralight card detected, running various tests.");
    ProcessUltralight();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mifare card detected, dumping the memory.");
    ProcessMifare();
}
```

but

```
res = mfrc522.ListenToCardIso14443TypeA(out card, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

is always false, i tried different cards and tags.
In the documentation they set 4 for pinReset, this didn't work, so i tried 22 because RST is Pin 22 but without success

The wiring is correct because if i run the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()
try:
    id, text = reader.read()
    print(id)
    print(text)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Everything works without problems.

I use a Raspberry 3 B+ and RC522 (https://joy-it.net/de/products/SBC-RFID-RC522).

**EDIT:**
I bought a Raspberry Compute Module 4, with the new Raspberry the library works and i get a card.

But if i try to read my Mifare 1k Cards i always get "Authentication error" the ret value from the Authcommand is always -1.

```
static void ProcessMifare()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(card.NfcId)}");
    var mifare = new MifareCard(mfrc522!, 0);
    mifare.SerialNumber = card.NfcId;
    mifare.Capacity = MifareCardCapacity.Mifare1K;
    mifare.KeyA = MifareCard.DefaultKeyA.ToArray();
    mifare.KeyB = MifareCard.DefaultKeyB.ToArray();
    int ret;

    for (byte block = 0; block < 64; block++)
    {
        mifare.BlockNumber = block;
        mifare.Command = MifareCardCommand.AuthenticationB;
        ret = mifare.RunMifareCardCommand();
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            // If you have an authentication error, you have to deselect and reselect the card again and retry
            // Those next lines shows how to try to authenticate with other known default keys
            mifare.ReselectCard();
            // Try the other key
            mifare.KeyA = MifareCard.DefaultKeyA.ToArray();
            mifare.Command = MifareCardCommand.AuthenticationA;
            ret = mifare.RunMifareCardCommand();
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                mifare.ReselectCard();
                mifare.KeyA = MifareCard.DefaultBlocksNdefKeyA.ToArray();
                mifare.Command = MifareCardCommand.AuthenticationA;
                ret = mifare.RunMifareCardCommand();
                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    mifare.ReselectCard();
                    mifare.KeyA = MifareCard.DefaultFirstBlockNdefKeyA.ToArray();
                    mifare.Command = MifareCardCommand.AuthenticationA;
                    ret = mifare.RunMifareCardCommand();
                    if (ret < 0)
                    {
                        mifare.ReselectCard();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error reading bloc: {block}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (ret >= 0)
        {
            mifare.BlockNumber = block;
            mifare.Command = MifareCardCommand.Read16Bytes;
            ret = mifare.RunMifareCardCommand();
            if (ret >= 0)
            {
                if (mifare.Data is object)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Bloc: {block}, Data: {BitConverter.ToString(mifare.Data)}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mifare.ReselectCard();
                Console.WriteLine($"Error reading bloc: {block}");
            }

            if (block % 4 == 3)
            {
                if (mifare.Data != null)
                {
                    // Check what are the permissions
                    for (byte j = 3; j > 0; j--)
                    {
                        var access = mifare.BlockAccess((byte)(block - j), mifare.Data);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Bloc: {block - j}, Access: {access}");
                    }

                    var sector = mifare.SectorTailerAccess(block, mifare.Data);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Bloc: {block}, Access: {sector}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Can't check any sector bloc");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication error ret is {ret}");
        }
    }
}
```

I used different cards but i'm getting always an error, exept the first time I read card, at the first time i got the memory dump until bloc 62 then i also got the Authentication error. But it only worked one time since then it never worked again, i also rebooted etc.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried with the provided example code?

Comment: Why do you set the CS line to 1? That would require you to use the second CS line for SPI bus 0, which, to be honest, I have never used and therefore might fail. When in doubt (and this reader is the only SPI device you use) you can also just hardwire the CS line of the reader to ground for testing.

Comment: i tried the example but without success. I set it to 1 because of the provided example, but i also tried it without a value (default is -1). the rc522 is the only SPI device i use

Comment: I don't have such a device, but I know this has been recently tested. I'll try to ping the responsible dev.

Comment: I was not able to get it run with the official solution, but i found another implementation that works for me. https://github.com/robertsundstrom/Iot-RPi-Sample/blob/master/src/Blink/RfidReader.cs

Comment: That's a bit weird, because that implementation uses the same low-level library as well, except that it uses a much older version. There must have been some breaking change somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure you are using GPIO7 as it's the Chip Select 1.
This binding works only when the chip select is properly used. It is very sensitive. So really make sure you are using the correct one.

Comment: I tried it with Pin 24 (GPIO8) and Chip Select 0 and with Pin 26 (GPIO7) and Chip Select 1. The python example uses Pin 24, if i execute my program with Pin 24 and 0 it blocks 24 and the python code stops working until i reboot so i think im accessing correct.

Comment: Make sure you also have properly activated the SPI and you are using the proper chip select there. See for a detailed explanation: https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/main/Documentation/raspi-spi.md

Comment: with the Raspberry Compute Module 4 the library works but now i have problems to read the memory, it worked one time but never worked again. I tried different cards, could it be that some Register entries are the problem?

Comment: When you say it works once, what do you mean exactly? any code snippet on what you're trying to do?

Comment: With once i mean, i installed the new test Program, then i held the card to the reader and it worked, authoriziation was successfull, i could read the bloc data from the card. But after this first try it never worked again, not with the same card nor with another card. 
I edited my Question with the code i use to read the data. (its the code from the sample)

Comment: Are you sure about the keys? I can read as many cards with the reader. Just have to make sure to call again the ListenToCardIso14443TypeA function